# Unable to receive the last socket data sent using the MSG_MORE flag

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

server side code:

```
 dirp=opendir(path);
    if(dirp==NULL)
    {
        strcpy(err,"error:");
        strcat(err,strerror(errno));
        send(fd,err,sizeof(err),0); 
    }       
    else
    {
        printf("\nstream opened\n");
        while((dp=readdir(dirp))!= NULL)
        {

            r=send(fd,dp->d_name,100,MSG_MORE);
            if(r<0)
                perror("\nsend:");
            printf("\n%s",dp->d_name);

        }
    }
```

client:

```
while(recv(mainsocket,lsbuf,100,0)>0)
{
    printf("\n %s",lsbuf);
    bzero(lsbuf,sizeof(lsbuf)); 
}
```

the server side is printing all the filenames on the standard output,but on the client side the client is not receiving the last filename and program is getting blocked at that point

Comment: This is probably not the reason, but maybe you just don't see it because it doesn't have a new line at the end and it is concatenated to next line?

Comment: How are you delimiting the data you send to your client, so it knows that it has received a whole file name (and not just a partial name, or even.. 2 names)

Comment: I guess that's why 100 is used as a send() length parameter. Each file name is sent as exactly 100 bytes, and that's how this code is supposed to work without any delimiters (the file name returned by readdir() is itself null-terminated, as far as I remember). Of course that would break with any longer file name (d_name is 256 bytes long on Linux) and is a horrible style in general.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the `send` syscall. You call it with `MSG_MORE` flag that means the more data will follow and send waits for more data without actually sending. The last chunk of data you should send without this flag. Thus your server side should look like:

```
dp = readdir(dirp);
if (dp != NULL)
{
    /* each time check whether there are more data */
    while((dp_next = readdir(dirp))!= NULL)
    {
        r = send(fd, dp->d_name, 100, MSG_MORE);
        if (r < 0) {
            perror("\nsend");
        }
        printf("\n%s",dp->d_name);
        dp = dp_next;
    }

    /* send the last or the only record */
    r = send(fd, dp->d_name, 100, 0);
    if (r < 0) {
        perror("\nsend");
    }
}
```

Another posibility to fix the problem is to close the conenction with the `close(fd)` syscall. It send all data in the buffer before closing the connection. It's a less clean, but more simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your client prints the newline *before* `lsbuf`, hence everything since the previous newline is lost in your output buffer.

Four solutions:

- use `printf("%s\n", lsbuf);` instead of `..."\n %s"...`
- use `puts(lsbuf);`, which has the same effect, but is slightly more appropriate
- use `fflush(stdout)` after your client loop to flush the output buffer
- use unbuffered output, see [setvbuf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) for details

Note that this problem doesn't seem to be networking-related (although I'd substitute `MSG_MORE` with `0`), it's merely a problem with output buffering.

On a sidenote, I strongly suggest to send `strlen(dp->d_name) + 1` bytes instead of 100 bytes. This way, you won't send more bytes than necessary, and on the other hand you won't truncate the output if your directory entries happen to be larger than 100 bytes.

Also, neither your client nor your server checks whether `send()`/`recv()` returns `0`, which means that the connection has been closed by the remote end.